# How to solve Fatal Exception error?

Tags: android

Now, I am developing one *JSON* project. All *JSON* values are stored in sqlLite database and the list view is displayed. Some values displayed it correctly and at that moment where the error is shown here below. Please help me.

```
12-08 19:00:27.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1042): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-08 19:00:27.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1042): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
12-08 19:00:27.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
12-08 19:00:27.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
12-08 19:00:27.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at ez.com.Action_module_screen.database(Action_module_screen.java:2443)
12-08 19:00:27.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at ez.com.Action_module_screen$2.handleMessage(Action_module_screen.java:623)
12-08 19:00:27.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-08 19:00:27.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-08 19:00:27.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-08 19:00:27.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-08 19:00:27.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-08 19:00:27.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
12-08 19:00:27.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
12-08 19:00:27.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3):

You're accessing `myList.get(0)` for an empty list.

The list might not be called `myList` (it probably isn't!) and the call might be `get(x)`, for instance, but that is what is happening.

Is `Action_module_screen` your own code? That's what's causing the error.